# How to fractionally split a column while doing a inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to basically split a column:

- Table A has 3 columns: Id, Name, Number
- Table b has 3 columns: Id, Name, School

I join on the basis of Id.

Suppose that the number is 100, the `Name` might have multiple schools (suppose 3), so I want to equally split 100 by 3 and do the join.

Sample Final Table

```
Id   Name   School   Number
---------------------------
 1   ABC      A       33.33
 1   ABC      B       33.33
 1   ABC      C       33.33
```

Comment: If you're storing multiple values in a single columns, **STOP THAT!** It's a sign you need an additional table, with each these values having their own record alongside the key from the original.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way we could do it without creating an additional table.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count for each `id` using [**`count(*) over(`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)`partition by a.Id)` and divide the number by that.

test setup: rextester: http://rextester.com/JQK48793

```
create table a (id int, name char(3), number decimal(9,2))
insert into a 
values (1,'ABC',100.0)

create table b (id int, name char(3), school char(1))
insert into b values 
 (1,'ABC','A')
,(1,'ABC','B')
,(1,'ABC','C')
```

query:

```
select 
     a.Id
  ,  a.Name
  ,  b.School
  ,  Number = (a.Number+.0) / count(*) over (partition by a.Id)
from a
  inner join b
    on a.Id = b.Id
```

results:

```
+----+------+--------+------------------+
| Id | Name | School |      Number      |
+----+------+--------+------------------+
|  1 | ABC  | A      | 33,3333333333333 |
|  1 | ABC  | B      | 33,3333333333333 |
|  1 | ABC  | C      | 33,3333333333333 |
+----+------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: Let me try this..  Thank you

Comment: @Pranav If you click on the rextester link in the answer, you can test it live online on rextester.com. http://rextester.com/JQK48793

Comment: Applying the same query to my table it is not splitting equally.. actual numbers differ from split numbers

Comment: @Pranav Can you update your question to include example data for your actual use case? That's a pretty vague problem.